# QueryDefs returns ~sq_rrptStatTabRout

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

**Situation:**
I need to lookup the first field of each query.  After I created the code listed below and executed it I received the following `Debug.Print`:

```
~sq_rrptStatTabRout
qryBridgeSub
qryCentTabRout
```

I was expecting the last two to print but I'm not particularly sure why the first one did since `rptStatTabRout` does exist in the database as a report.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to explain this or get rid of it?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim queries As DAO.QueryDefs
Dim query As DAO.QueryDef
Dim queryname As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set queries = db.QueryDefs

' loop through each query
For Each query In queries
    On Error Resume Next

    queryname = query.name
    Debug.Print queryname
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & queryname & "", dbOpenDynaset)
    fld = rs.Fields(0).name

    MsgBox fld

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be careful with `On Error Resume Next`.  That directive ignores errors without letting you know they happened or why.  And that lack of information can be a severe handicap during troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want to ignore saved queries whose names start with `~`.  Use an `If` condition to ignore them.

```vb
If Not query.Name Like "~*" Then
   ' find the first field
End If
```

Note if you want to limit the evaluation to only `SELECT` queries, check each query's `.Type` property.  A `SELECT` query is type *dbQSelect* (0).  Check the *QueryDef.Type Property* topic in Access' help system in case you want to process other query types.

If you're wondering where that *~sq_rrptStatTabRout* query came from, check the *Record Source* property of your *rptStatTabRout* report.  When the source is a `SELECT` statement, Access saves the statement as a hidden query.  The `~` prefix prevents it from being displayed in the Navigation pane.

The same thing happens when you use a `SELECT` statement as the *Row Source* for a combo or list box.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I highly regret running your code before noticing that you run each query.  Made for interesting times since I have 50+ queries..

I modified your code to help explain what is happening, the code is limited to 10 iterations because saved queries seem to be shown first and were getting pushed out of my immediate window.

```
Public Function Test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim queries As DAO.QueryDefs
    Dim query As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim queryname As String
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set queries = db.QueryDefs

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    ' loop through each query
    For Each query In queries
        On Error Resume Next

        If i < 10 Then

            Debug.Print query.Name
            Debug.Print query.SQL
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next


End Function
```

If you run that you can see the actual SQL it found in your `rptStatTabRout` report.  This is because there are more queries in `QueryDefs` than just the ones you see in your navigation pane.

In your example take a look at the `RecordSource` for your report and I suspect you will find a written query.  It will even find sql in the `RowSource` for comboboxes as well.